# Typescript says that the index property of individual matchAll() matches is (number | undefined)

Tags: typescript

I get an error

```
Type '(number | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
```

when I write

```
const nums: number[] = [...'a'.matchAll(/a/g)].map(match => match.index);
```

but MDN doesn't say anything about this property being optional.
Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: I hesitate to say it's a bug because it almost always is because of some non-obvious language-lawyer cornercase, but I can't think of how this is correct. According to [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll#return_value) the returned iterator should have the same type as the return of `Regex.prototype.exec`, and a quick check indicates that `.index` is [not optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDAFAejpglAOgFMAPQ4dAcjgtwCgBLAMw0QVxgG9aYeZRJYAI0Sp4SfPTAATEjEyYYYAK4BbQYQS0AvtxhA).

Comment: @Blackhole that's an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in TypeScript; [the issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36788) has been reported in 2020. For now, you can safely assert that `match.index` is a `number`.